# Disable all hyperlinks in any website

Tags: javascript, firefox, web, chromium

Is there a way to disable all hyperlinks in any website using javascript?

The reason I want to do this is for text-selection. Many websites are putting whole blocks of text inside  tags, making it difficult to select text.

I use chromium and firefox on kubuntu 13.10.

Comment: You can loop over [*document.links*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#dom-document-links), which is a collection of all links in a page, and add a listener to prevent navigation.

Comment: Alternatively, just remove the *href* attribute so they are no longer links.

Comment: @RobG Could you please test this trick on http://nos.nl/ ? On the left side, after all href attributes are removed, some blocks still behave as if they are links.

Answer (score 8):

To disable all links use

```
$('a').bind("click.myDisable", function() { 
   return false; 
});
```

and to enable it use

```
$('a').unbind("click.myDisable");
```

Comment: This is a better answer bc you can re-enable links if you want to later and it is clear and concise.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is. You can use [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) addon for Firefox and [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) for Chrome to achieve this.

**UPDATE**

use this in greasemonkey. it will replace all links with spans. this way they can be selected like normal text:

```
// @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.js

(function($) {
    $.fn.changeElementType = function(newType) {
        var attrs = {};

        $.each(this[0].attributes, function(idx, attr) {
            attrs[attr.nodeName] = attr.nodeValue;
        });

        this.replaceWith(function() {
            return $("<" + newType + "/>", attrs).append($(this).contents());
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$('a').changeElementType('span');
```

---

**old** (not working well):

the script could be:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++)
{
  links[i].href='#';
  links[i].onclick = function(){  return false; };
}
```

Comment: With this method the links are indeed disable, but text-selection has also become impossible. Double click does not select a word, and click -and-drag does not select anything.

Comment: A elements are not necessarily links, they might be anchors. Adding an href property will turn them into links when they weren't in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Okay completely different answer to my deleted answer using what Rob G said.

```
for (var x=document.links.length-1;x>=0;x--) {
document.links[x].removeAttribute("href")
}
```

Comment: Your first answer works better. :) With this one, clicking on a link brings you to an undefined page. Try this url: http://nos.nl/

Answer (score 1):

```
function replaceA(element) {
    for (var i=element.children.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
        var getChild = element.children[i];
        if (getChild.tagName == "A") {
            element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(getChild.outerHTML,getChild.innerHTML);
        } else {
            replaceA(getChild);
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function(){replaceA(document.body)};
```

A bit hacky, basically when page has loaded, it will replace all links with just their innerHTML text. If you wanna use it instead of when the page loads, just remove the window.onload part, and call replaceA(document.body) when you wish to use it

Comment: Why loop over every element in the page when [*document.links*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#dom-document-links) is a ready–made collection of all the links in the page?

Comment: Just a lazy way of knowing what the parent is so I can replace the innerHTML of the parent element containing the link

Answer (score 1):

According to this forum thread, there are some options:

1. I usually paste it into 'TextEdit' and making sure that TexEdit is displaying fonts as Plain Text. Then copy the links or texts from TexEdit and paste it into Pages.
2. Open the Inspector palette. Select the second last tab called "Link Inspector", then highlight the link itself. Click the "Enable as a hyperlink" checkbox to off and it will disappear.
3. In Pages preferences, there's an option on the "Auto Correct" tab to "Automatically detect email and web addresses". Untick that and it shouldn't happen if what you're pasting contains a URL or an email address.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to clean text of links using javascript. Also, TextEdit, Pages, and the Inspector are all Mac applications/features. OP is on kubuntu and won't have access to those tools.